# Get params from screen in another screen navigation V5 REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im trying to get the params from screen A in screen B, but is always throwing error, this is the way im doing it:

```
go = (songs) => {
        this.props?.navigation.navigate("Artists_Song", {hola: "hola"});
 }

 <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.go(songs)}>
                                    <View style = {{
                                        backgroundColor: "yellow", 
                                        width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.48, 
                                        marginBottom: 20, 
                                        marginLeft: 5, 
                                        alignItems: "center"}}
                                        key = {artist}>
                                        <Image source = {require("../assets/default_image.jpg")} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.48, height: 100}}></Image>
                                        <Text style = {{fontSize: 20, textAlign: "center"}}>
                                            {
                                                (artist.length > 15) ?  
                                                artist.substring(0,13).padEnd(15,".") 
                                                : artist
                                            }
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
```

and in Artists_Song:

```
class Artists_Song extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <>
            <Artist_Song {...this.props}></Artist_Song>
        </>
    )
}
```

and in the final component where it should be printed:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const songs = this.props.route.params;
    console.log(songs);
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Text>Hola</Text>
        </>
    )
}
```

also tried with:

```
this.props.route.params.hola
```

```
this.props.navigation.route.params
```

Comment: could you check `this.props.navigation.state.params`

Comment: it tells: undefined is not an object evaluating ```this.props.navigation.state.params```

Comment: whare is the version of react-navigation you are using?

Comment: @jogesh_pi navigation v5